# Unable to run a script at launch in Ubuntu

Tags: server, 20.04, services, init.d

I just want to execute a script when the system starts, and after many tries and following multiple tutorials and documentation, I am unable to do it.

Could you spot what am I doing wrong?

Run Ubuntu 20.04 in docker:

```
docker run -d --name daemon ubuntu:20.04 tail -f /dev/null
```

Connect to it:

```
docker exec -it daemon /bin/bash
```

Write `/etc/init.d/test`:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Join the Swarm
# Default-Start:     4
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Description:       Join the Swarm
### END INIT INFO
start(){
        /usr/bin/echo start >> /var/log/test.log
}
stop(){
        /usr/bin/echo stop >> /var/log/test.log
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start;;
  stop)
    stop;;
  status)
    cat /var/log/test.log;;
  restart)
    stop;
    start;
    ;;
  *);;
esac
exit 0;
```

Set permissions and enable the service:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/test
update-rc.d test defaults 91
update-rc.d test enable
```

Check that it actually works:

```
service test restart
service test status
```

It should output:

```
stop
start
```

Remove the log file and exit the session:

```
rm -rf /var/log/test.log
exit
```

Reboot the container, and connect to it again:

```
docker restart daemon
docker exec -it daemon /bin/bash
```

Check the service is actually active:

```
service --status-all
```

Unfortunately it did never executed:

```
root@407a8e2c90ee:/# service test status
cat: /var/log/test.log: No such file or directory
```

It seems the RC are fine:

```
root@407a8e2c90ee:/# ls /etc/rc*.d
/etc/rc0.d:
K01test

/etc/rc1.d:

/etc/rc2.d:

/etc/rc3.d:

/etc/rc4.d:
S01test

/etc/rc5.d:

/etc/rc6.d:
K01test

/etc/rcS.d:
S01procps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I understood from your question: you want to start an ubuntu:20.04 container and inside this container should start an additional service.

1. it's great to have you in the container supporters family.
2. the issue you describe is not related towards ubuntu, it is the default behaviour of containers.
3. when starting a container a single script is executed, in your case `tail -f /dev/null` - nothing else. an Ubuntu container is not a full ubuntu VM !
4. the regular ubuntu boot process does not happen inside a container. you Service is never touched.
   How to proceed:
5. instead of using `docker run ...` I recommend to checkout `docker-compose` and the syntax of the `docker-compose.yaml` file
6. checkout the parameter `command` or `entrypoint`

Comment: ‍♂️  Actually I was trying to do this in a cloud virtual machine, but I was using the container locally to test my approach. I saved the changes hopping to get an answer later, and it worked, but I did not understand why in the VM yes but in the container not. Now I get it. Thank you very much!

One last thing though... In that example I posted, will `stop()` execute correctly when the system is shutting down or rebooting?

Comment: gues you reference to the `stop()` in `/etc/init.d/test` ? 
this command does nothing as it is never executed. if it is executed it sends a message to `/var/log/test.log`, if it is executed inside the container it sends the message to the file inside the container and not of the host. use `docker-compose` and `volumes` if you want to change this.